# Keyboard doesn't function after Fedora 17 update

Tags: keyboard, fedora, fedora-17

I updated my Fedora 16 installation to Fedora 17 on Saturday, and the update worked without reporting any errors. I carried on working on the machine in question and then switched the computer off.

Last night I went back on the computer, I switched it on and got to the log in screen. At this point I tried to type in my password but the keyboard wouldn't work. I unplugged it (it's a PS/2 keyboard) and plugged it back in. The lights flashed for a split second but the keyboard still wouldn't work. I then plugged the keybaord in to a USB to PS/2 adapter, and the keyboard still wouldn't work.

I restarted the computer and tried to access the BIOS and I was able to do so. So the keyboard doesn't seem to be faulty, it just doesn't work when Fedora boots in to the GUI interface.

I did try to boot in to the "recovery mode" of Fedora, and the keyboard works here with no problem.

As I still have access to Fedora via a terminal interface, is there anything I can do to fix the keyboard problem via the terminal without having to reinstall Fedora?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem. 
In a terminal try:

```
sudo system-config-keyboard
```

Choose you keyboard language. 
That made it correct for me. The only problem I seem to have is that if I reboot, it get reset again.

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't work. I've ended up getting the Fedora 17 disc and replacing the current OS with this. Thanks anyway!